# Add GROUP Name and Subtotal in SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this SQL code and it works fine, but I want to show the department name and total of departments before the group by start.

Please look at the screenshot for more detail:

[image: look Example In Picture]

```
select department, EmpName, Sum(Debi), sum(Credi)
from Total_Income
group by EmpName, Department
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: It is not, what SQL should take care of? These type of manipulation should be done in application layer. I'm not saying it can not be done in SQL but not a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by rollup`:

```
select department, coalesce(EmpName, 'Total'), Sum(Debi), sum(Credi)
from Total_Income
group by rollup (department, EmpName)
having department is not null
order by department, case when EmpName is null then 0 else 1 end, EmpName
```

(Optional SQL standard feature T431, Extended grouping capabilities.)